# Angular 8 How to add/remove CSS class with a delay

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-directive

I have an angular component with following snippet in template

```
`<div class="articleContainer">
    <div class="mrFaqArticle {{listParent}} active">
        <ul class="choice">
            <li *ngFor="let intent of intents">
                <div class="bal">
                    <a class="label"(click)="selectIntent(intent)">{{intent.title}}</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>`
```

And following method in the component which does simple animation using css classes

```
`animateIntentList() {
    document.querySelector(".mrFaqArticle").classList.remove("fadeIn", "fadeOut");
    document.querySelector(".mrFaqArticle.active").classList.add("fadeOut");
    document.querySelector(".mrFaqArticle.active").classList.remove('active');

    setTimeout(()=>{
        document.querySelector(`.mrFaqArticle.${this.listParent} .choice`).classList.add('stagger');
        document.querySelector(`.mrFaqArticle.${this.listParent}`).classList.add('active', 'fadeIn');
    },320);
}`
```

Is there a way to implement the above using directive, as accessing DOM element by query selector is considered bad practice.

Comment: Why a directive? Angular has quite a good animation system build in: https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: Looking for generic approach using directive, so that the CSS classes with transitions could be used directly. Angular animation would involve adding all those transitions in the decorator of component.

Comment: You can perfectly re-use animations... but whatever you prefer..

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use ngClass or ngStyle ?

Comment: Yes, but how to add class with a delay using ngClass

Comment: you can add delay using setTimeout when you're changing ngClass 's value in code (.ts).

Comment: I am already using setTimeOut in ts. Can you please explain more

Comment: Hi, You can try to make use of ```animation-delay``` css property itself it `animation-delay:2s`. Along with you can use ```animation``` property with ```@keyFrames```
[Delay using css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-delay)